# how to declare the variable type instead of any

Tags: angular, typescript

Can anyone explain for user_roles variable instead of any type I need to mention object type. How to do it in typescript way.

```
user_roles: any = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
    role: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl(''),
  })
```

Comment: Have you tried not putting `: any` so that you will let Typescript infer the type?

Comment: See [here](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms). Please note you have to use angular14.

Comment: In your case FormGroup is the type...

Comment: FormGroup IS the type

Answer (score 0):

you can use FormGroup Instead of any

```
user_roles: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
name: new FormControl(''),
email: new FormControl(''),
role: new FormControl(''),
password: new FormControl(''),
```

})